# How to evaluate the integral $\int\frac{1-e^{-2y} -\frac{2}{k}\ln{(1+ky)}}{(1+ky)e^{-2y}-1}dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Please help me in doing this integration.
$\int_{0}^{m}\frac{1-e^{-2y} -\frac{2}{k}\ln{(1+ky)}}{(1+ky)e^{-2y}-1}dy$
where m is a positive number.

Comment: are you shure you rewrote it correctly,maby you forgot the bonds

Comment: @Booldy what do you mean by bonds..?

Comment: it might be definite integral with certain bonds,indefinite integral cannot be calculated by mathematica

Comment: @Booldy you can take the limits as 0 to m , where m is a constant and m>0